# React Native infinite loop using setState with Food Data Central API (USDA)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

**Desired**

I want to query the data within the Food Data Central open API to display in an application.

FDC API: https://fdc.nal.usda.gov/api-guide.html

**Issue**

An infinite loop when trying to use setState to record the data retrieved from the FDC food database.

Here is the code I currently have.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

   const [data, setData] = useState([]);

   const getRecipes = async() => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=(MY_KEY_HERE)&query=Cheddar%20Cheese&pageSize=1'
    )

    const dataGrabbed = await response.json();
    
    setData(dataGrabbed);
  }

  getRecipes();

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24, }}>
      <Text> This is just used as a placeholder </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Now the problem is that this does properly assign the data grabbed from the FDC API to "data" however it creates an infinite loop due to what I am assuming (after a lot of research) is the render function being called every time the setData is called which in turn triggers the function over again.

Is there any way to use setData without the infinite loop? Merely so that I can display the data provided in the return function?

**NOTE:** I have also attempted using the class component structure in react native, but have had better results using functional component structure.

(I am extremely new to JavaScript and React Native).

Comment: where do you call `getRecipes` ?

Comment: @givehug Whoops... I was calling it right after the function declaration. I must have removed it due to the issues I was having. I'll change that now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that causes infinite looping in your case is because of re-rendering of the functional component everytime you set something to state. FYI, every time you call any of the function from **useState** to update the value of the state the component re-renders and if the component re-renders understand that all your variables are called again so you can not directly create this **const getRecipes**.

To avoid any such behavior you can use another hook from React i.e. **useEffect** which will help you in making this call only when required for example only on initial mounting of the component or when some values change in your component. To understand more about it please read more about this hook at https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html.

For your case you can change your component to something like below:-

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const response = await fetch(
     'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=(MY_KEY_HERE)&query=Cheddar%20Cheese&pageSize=1'
    );
    const dataGrabbed = await response.json();
    setData(dataGrabbed);
  }, [])    

  console.log(data);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24, }}>
      <Text> This is just used as a placeholder </Text>
    </View>
  )
}
```

This **useEffect** will only make the API call on initial mount of the component and no more infinite looping. Enjoy!

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much. The function does set the state of data correctly and it solved my loop problem. One thing if you have time... running this returned an error:            


"Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.%s%s,

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately".  Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. React had a very helpful error code that almost fixed the issue for me. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

you have to import useEffect from React to initialize the state of your "screen" and read more about it, i write a example of how should be used:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import {
Text,
View,
} from 'react-native';

export default function App() {

const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect (()=> {
const response = await fetch(
  'https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=(MY_KEY_HERE)&query=Cheddar%20Cheese&pageSize=1'
);
const dataGrabbed = await response.json();
setData(dataGrabbed);
}, []);

return (
<View style={{ flex: 1, padding: 24, }}>
  <Text> This is just used as a placeholder </Text>
</View>
)
}
```

Comment: This almost works but without the async function in there the await runs into issues. The above answer clarified it the best for me. Thank you!

Comment: you're welcome, i learn too haha, i use redux sagas for my calls to the api :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your api in useEffect()

```
useEffect(() => {
   // api call goes here
}, []);
```

Comment: Yes, the above two answers both clarified that for me. Thank you!